# I'm looking for a way to bloat and fill up my Android device for testing

Tags: android

Basically, I'm running tests of an app on Android, and getting some mixed errors/crashes. Basically, we've come to a conclusion that our Android testing device, which is a Pixel 7 is "way too clean of an Android" and I'm looking for a way to bloat it up, install some random apps, fill up cache and memory etc., as close to real life use as possible.

Does anyone know a know to achieve this?

I did try installing some random apps, log in, allow everything etc. but it's taking too much time.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your app so you know how much memory etc. it's using? IIRC, the OS can "kill" an app if it uses too many resources, and profiling would tell you how much it's using. And does TestFairy or equivalent still exist so you can roll it out to beta testers?